# Show $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{R}x_{j} = \operatorname{max} \{ x^{T}z: 0 \leq z \leq 1, \mathbb{1}^{T}z = R\}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, numerical-methods, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Let $x=(x_{1},...,x_{n})\in \mathbb R^{n}$ so that $x_{1} \geq x_{2} \geq ... \geq x_{n}$ and further $R  \in \{1,...,n\}$.

Show that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{R}x_{j} = \operatorname{max} \{ x^{T}z: 0 \leq z \leq 1, \mathbb{1}^{T}z = R\}$

Initially I thought of induction, but this would not make sense since $R$ is finite.

Other idea:

consider the LP:

$\operatorname{max} x^{T}z$

s.t. $z \leq 1$, $-z \leq 0$ and $\mathbb{1}^{T}z \leq R$ and $-\mathbb{1}^{T}z \leq -R$

We consider the dual

$  \operatorname{max}-(1 ,0,R,-R)\begin{pmatrix} y_{1} \\ y_{2} \\\lambda_{1} \\ \lambda_{2} \end{pmatrix}$

s.t. $(E_{n}, -E_{n}, 1, -1) \begin{pmatrix} y_{1} \\ y_{2} \\\lambda_{1} \\ \lambda_{2} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\.. \\ x_{n} \end{pmatrix}$ and 
$\begin{pmatrix} y_{1} \\ y_{2} \\\lambda_{1} \\ \lambda_{2} \end{pmatrix}\geq 0$

We can thus identify $y=y_{1}-y_{2}$ with an arbitrary vector and $\lambda=\lambda^{1}-\lambda^{2}$ as an arbitrary scalar so we want to solve

$y +\lambda 1 = x$

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primal LP problem is to maximize $\sum_j x_j z_j$ subject to
\begin{align}
z_j &\le 1 && (\text{dual $\alpha_j \ge 0$})\\
\sum_j z_j &= R && (\text{dual $\beta$ free})\\
z_j &\ge 0
\end{align}
Taking $$z_j=\begin{cases}1&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,R\}$}\\0&\text{for $j\in\{R+1,\dots,n\}$}\end{cases}$$ is primal feasible with objective value $\sum_{j=1}^R x_j$.
The dual LP problem is to minimize $\sum_j \alpha_j+R\beta$ subject to
\begin{align}
\alpha_j +\beta &\ge x_j && (\text{dual $z_j \ge 0$})\\
\alpha_j &\ge 0
\end{align}
Taking $\beta=x_R$ and
$$\alpha_j=\begin{cases}x_j-x_R&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,R\}$}\\0&\text{for $j\in\{R+1,\dots,n\}$}\end{cases}$$
is dual feasible (this uses the fact that $x_j$ is nonincreasing) with objective value
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j+R\beta
=\sum_{j=1}^R \alpha_j+\sum_{j=R+1}^n \alpha_j+R\beta
=\sum_{j=1}^R (x_j-x_R)+\sum_{j=R+1}^n 0+R x_R
=\sum_{j=1}^R x_j,$$
which matches the primal objective value, certifying optimality of this primal-dual pair.